# Link Wordpress Comment Admin Author name with About page

Tags: redirect, author, username

I am looking for a functions.php code which will link my admin author name in WordPress Comments to the About page of the admin. Currently the code I am using links my post admin author name with the about page perfectly, however the comment admin author name still links to the homepage of the blog.

When I inspect the comment admin author name, I get the following details:

```
<span class="comment-author-link"><a href="https://www.domain.com/" class="url" rel="ugc">admin</a></span>
```

The code for linking the post admin author name with the about page is given below, it works perfectly well:

```
add_filter( 'author_link', 'my_author_link' );
function my_author_link() {
    return home_url( 'about/' );
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Best guess comments by logged in users are saved with the name. email and URL they had at the time and not linked to user IDs. So if you write a new comment it should have the correct URL but for old comments you'd need to update the values in the wp_comment table.